# ErrorException in AssetController.php line 21: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this code source that i'm trying to use in one of my projects, it worked with laravel 5.2. This the function in the assetController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Setting;
use File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AssetController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * List all image from image directory
     */
    public function getAsset()
    {
        //Get Admin Images
        $adminImages = array();
        //get image file array
        $images_dir = Setting::where('name', 'images_dir')->first();
        $folderContentAdmin = File::files($images_dir->value);

        //check the allowed file extension and make the allowed file array
        $allowedExt = Setting::where('name', 'images_allowedExtensions')->first();
        $temp = explode('|', $allowedExt->value);
        foreach ($folderContentAdmin as $key => $item)
        {
            if( ! is_array($item))
            {
                //check the file extension
                $ext = pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                //prep allowed extensions array
                if (in_array($ext, $temp))
                {
                    array_push($adminImages, $item);
                }
            }
        }

        //Get User Images
        $userImages = array();
        $userID = Auth::user()->id;
        $images_uploadDir = Setting::where('name', 'images_uploadDir')->first();
        if (is_dir( $images_uploadDir->value . "/" .$userID ))
        {
            $folderContentUser = File::files($images_uploadDir->value . "/" .$userID );
            if ($folderContentUser)
            {
                foreach ($folderContentUser as $key => $item)
                {
                    if ( ! is_array($item))
                    {
                        //check the file extension
                        $ext = pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        //prep allowed extensions array
                        //$temp = explode("|", $this->config->item('images_allowedExtensions'));
                        if (in_array($ext, $temp))
                        {
                            array_push($userImages, $item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //var_dump($folderContent);
        //var_dump($adminImages);

        return view('assets/images', compact('adminImages', 'userImages'));
    }
```

The problem is in the line 21 :

```
//get image file array
        $images_dir = Setting::where('name', 'images_dir')->first();
        $folderContentAdmin = File::files($images_dir->value);
```

From my research I find out that the reason is because the setting table is empty which it is true. 
Please tell me if there is another cause to that problem if it's not the case I need a solution because I don't have a way to fill that table except doing it from the database itself (phpmyAdmin)

Comment: It seems your `Setting` table is empty with these wheres. Replace `->first()` with `->firstOrFail()` to make sure for yourself....

Comment: Yes the table is empty i used firstOrFail() and that's the result No query results for model [App\Setting].

Comment: I don't how are you populating your `Setting` table but that's your problem. You should have something there that matches column `name` with value `images_dir`

Comment: This are the attributes in the setting table: id name value default_value description required created_at updated_at

Comment: As i said this code is not mine i'm just trying to use it in my project by adding more features. Now i need a way to proceed even if the table is empty

Comment: If you want to make your code work you need to add to `Setting` table at least one row. Column `name` with value `images_dir` and column `value` with value `{your desired directory to store images}`. Same for `default_value` column. `required` column should have TRUE (but maybe different for example 1 depending db definition). Other fields doesn't seem important. BTW all this db config with Setting table seems little bit weird. And probably you will hit other problems. Shortest way would be to copy `Setting` table data from other system...